# Backup password for MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, passwords

I am creating a game in C# and Unity that accesses a MySql database. The database contains private information including users' emails and passwords. It also contains data used by the game's inventory. I want to know if it's possible to make it that when a person tries to access the database, it asks them for a backup password, yet Unity doesn't need the password so that hackers can't access the database. If this isn't possible, is it possible to set the database to accept changes from only C# scripts or specific IP addresses?

Comment: For context, what are you using the database for? High scores?

Comment: So remote users need to be able to write and read to the database? You should use a different protocol like HTTP so you can have exact control over what a user can get and push.

Comment: Is this a shared database that will be used by multiple users? If so, direct connections to the database aren't the way to go. You'll want to separate the application from the database by using an intermediate application, such as a webservice (eg. WebAPI).

Comment: Is this server-side MySQL? Is this something users will be expected to deploy themselves? Consider using something embeddable like SQLite instead if it's for end-user use.

Comment: You don't. You put an application server in between the database and your end-user applications that will handle things like authentication and security.

Comment: webapi is a good starting point to make a RESTful application server. Make sure to find recent, well-sourced articles on how to implement or use a proper identity model.

Comment: @willaien Ok, so i just checked out my hosting site, and it says that i can add directory privacy, which is a password for certain folders. If i enable this, will c# need this password? If not, that's my problem solved.